# How to redirect query string to static url?

Tags: php, redirect

Our website is currently using following URL pattern:
https://www.example.com/country_events.php?country=Bahrain

We want to adopt following URL pattern:
https://www.example.com/Bahrain.php

How would we do that?

We tried a number of query string redirects. But none of them worked.

Comment: You should describe your environment (linux, Wamp), framework (wordpress, codeigniter) etc.

Comment: The only way I know to redirect from PHP is `header('Location: https://www.example.com/Bahrain.php');` and it does work if used properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+).php$ country_events.php?country=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you @Abhiashek for your prompt response. However the code isn't working either. Do I need to replace any any value in the code?

Comment: what is the error and where are you applying? it is working for me please check.